# Get_stylesheet_directory_uri или get_stylesheet_directory?

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим в файле `functions.php` нужно добавить свой js-скрипт с помощью  `wp_add_inline_script`, который находится в другой папке.
Какую функцию использовать: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` или `get_stylesheet_directory` ?

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    $custom_js = file_get_contents(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/main.js');

    //произвольный код js
    wp_add_inline_script('jquery', $custom_js);
});
```

т.е. для удобства, чтобы не прописывать js прямо в `functions.php`, нужно импортировать скрипт не с помощью `wp_enqueue_script`, а с помощью `wp_add_inline_script`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `get_stylesheet_directory()` возвращает **путь** к файлу вида `/var/www/my-site/wp-content/themes/my-theme`.

Функция `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` возвращает **url** к файлу вида `http://my-site.org/wp-content/themes/my-theme`.

В вашем случае результат работы `file_get_contents()` будет одинаковый. Вот только гонять лишний http-запрос через сервер нет никакой необходимости, лучше получить содержимое прямым доступом к файлу, с помощью `get_stylesheet_directory()`.